# Set title of pdf using mpdf file codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

```
$this->load->library('m_pdf');

$pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();

$pdf->SetTitle('My Doc');

$pdf->WriteHTML($html);

$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
```

Used `SetTitle()` function of mpdf but by default it is using name of file :  "Untitled Document - _Test_Company_10120.pdf"

Also set the `<title></title>` tag but no use.

Comment: can you show your `$pdfFilePath` location and name?

Comment: M storing the file into server

Comment: Can you pdf file download or save root directory?

Comment: Please show your `$pdfFilePath` value. you can used `$pdf->SetTitle('My Doc');`. 

But Set the title for the document. The title is displayed at the top of the Adobe Reader screen when viewing the PDF file, and is include in the document metadata, which can be seen when inspecting the document properties in Adobe Reader.

Comment: @razibalmamun Yes m saving on Server on pdf_files folder.

Comment: Why you can not show `$pdfFilePath` value?

Comment: Show me `$pdfFilePath` variable how initialize and which content.

Comment: @razibalmamun :  $pdfFilePath = FCPATH . "/assets/pdf/my_document.pdf";

Answer (score 0):

You used `$pdf->SetTitle('My Doc');`
Set the title for the document. The title is displayed at the top of the Adobe Reader screen when viewing the PDF file, and is include in the document metadata, which can be seen when inspecting the document properties in Adobe Reader.

So, Try this :

```
$pdfFilePath = "directory/your_pdf_name.pdf";
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
```